# In Blazor server side, how do I extend the amount of time the user can be idle before disconnecting from the server?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a website where my users may be idle for a while then resume using my website. Blazor server side is timing out too quickly for this use case, ideally I would like the website to be available for 8 - 10 hours or so. How do I extend the amount of time that my website stays connected to my server?

Comment: I didn't think that the SignalR connection would break itself. How are you hosting the application, with IIS?

Comment: I believe so yes

Comment: We have it on Azure

Comment: Is your hosting provider turning off your application when idle?

Comment: I don't know, I will try to figure out how to check that in Azure

Comment: How do you host it? App Service? Function App? VM? AKS Cluster? What does 'too quickly' mean? What is the timeout right now?

Comment: Does it surely times out when it is hosted, or do you maybe mean when you are running it with visual studio?